# iOS 9 press ok GameCenterDashboardExtension have console message

Tags: ios, game-center, ios9, game-center-leaderboard

I have a message when press ok when dismiss the view.

**plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated**

What can i do?